# c# Reflection of a nested struct property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to do some dynamic text to object parsing, however, I have run into a snag when creating and setting nested property values for structs.

If I have a property in an object that is a struct, whenever I use reflection to obtain the struct object and set any of it's properties/fields, the value on the object is not changed.  Take the object graph below.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int MyIntProp {get;set;}
}

public class MyObj
{
    public MyStruct NestedStruct {get;set;}
}

PropertyInfo pInfo = (myObj.GetType()).GetProperty("NestedStruct");
object nestedStruct = pInfo.GetValue(myObj); // This is the nested struct however it is only a copy not the actual object
PropertyInfo intInfo = (pInfo.PropertyType).GetProperty("MyIntProp");
intInfo.SetValue(nestedStruct, 23); // this sets the MyIntProp on the nestedStruct, but it is not set on the myObj.NestedStruct.  My goal is to set object on that NestedStruct via reflection.
```

When I use reflection to obtain the NestedStruct property and then set the MyIntProp on that struct, the original MyObj.NestedStruct.MyIntProp doesn't change.  Naturally I attribute this to the fact that the struct is a value type and not a reference type.

So the real question is how I can use reflection to obtain the reference to a value type.

Comment: Any chance you could avoid having mutable structs to start with?

Comment: It's really for a library that I'm making that will allow parsing of delimited files into dynamic object.  So far it works find with pure reference type object.  however, when getting into value type containers I seem to be running into this problem.

Comment: So don't use "value type containers". Mutable structs are just bad news, basically.

Comment: I see.  The project I'm working on deals with motion simulation.  As such I have motion objects that contain pure value types (mainly doubles).  At the time I was thinking that making the motion object immutable would be advantageous preventing any calling methods from corruption original data.  Perhaps that was the wrong reasoning for using structs?  I was sort of thinking of them similar to the DateTime or TimeSpan object.

Comment: Using structs may well be fine (I can't tell without more context) - but the example you've given clearly *isn't* immutable!

Comment: that's a good point.  I was trying to make this parser an all case any use parser and perhaps that was the wrong way to go.   I appreciate your feedback I have learned a tremendous amount from you via SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I have a property in an object that is a struct, whenever I use reflection to obtain the struct object and set any of it's properties/fields, the value on the object is not changed.

Well, no - because on this line:

```
object nestedStruct = pInfo.GetValue(myObj);
```

... you're copying the value, as it's a value type. You're also boxing it - which is fine, because it means when you mutate it in the `intInfo.SetValue` call, it's the boxed copy which is modified. (If you were boxing it at the point of calling `intInfo.SetValue`, that would really be hopeless.)

After you've made the change within the boxed copy, you then need to set it *back* into the property of the object:

```
pInfo.SetValue(myObject, nestedStruct);
```

It would be instructive to try doing what you're doing *not* using reflection:

```
MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
myObj.NestedStruct.MyIntProp = 23;
```

The compiler will give you an error on the last line, explaining that it's a silly thing to do:

> Test.cs(20,9): error CS1612: Cannot modify the return value of 'MyObj.NestedStruct' because it is not a variable

Comment: Of all my time that I've used structs I've never run into that.  I'm not really sure I understand why.  Can you point me to some documentation that might explain why it is not a variable?

Comment: After thinking about it, it makes perfect sense why it is not a variable, it being a set of properties rather than fields.

Comment: @galford13x: Glad I didn't need to try to get into it :) (I've only just seen your previous comment, I'm afraid.)